# Simulate as3.0 hitTestobject in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, hittest

Im trying to write a function similar to as3.0's hit test in javascript. 
I place circles on the screen which is defined in div tags, then I go through all of the circle to see if their positions overlap.

The contents in the html file:

```
<div class="balls">
  <script>
    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
      document.write("<div id='ball"+i+"' class='ball'></div>");
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

Placing them using jquery:

```
var amount = 10;
var height = 270;
var width = 450;
  function setBalls(){
    for (i=0;i<amount;i++){
      $("#ball"+i).css('top',parseInt(Math.random()*height)+'px');
      $("#ball"+i).css('left',parseInt(Math.random()*width)+'px');
      for (j=0;j<i;j++){
        hitTest($("#ball"+i),$("#ball"+j));
      }
    }
}
```

The hitTest function as called above:

```
function hitTest(object1,object2){
  var left1 = parseInt(object1.css('left'));
  var left2 = parseInt(object2.css('left'));
  var top1 = parseInt(object1.css('top'));
  var top2 = parseInt(object2.css('top'));
  var width1 = parseInt(object1.width());
  var width2 = parseInt(object2.width());
  var height1 = parseInt(object1.height());
  var height2 = parseInt(object2.height());
  var horTest = false;
  var verTest = false;
  if (((left1 >= left2)&&(left1 <= left2 + width2))||((left2 >= left1)&&(left2 <= left1 + width1))){
    horTest = true;
  }
  if (((top1 >= top2)&&(top1 <= top2 + height2))||((top2 >= top1)&&(top2 <= top1 + height1))){
    verTest = true;
  }
  if(horTest&&verTest){
    console.log("hit");
    object1.css('top',parseInt(Math.random()*height)+'px');
    object1.css('left',parseInt(Math.random()*width)+'px');
    hitTest(object1,object2);
  } 
}
```

The stylesheet info:

```
.ball{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:green;
  border-radius:100%;
  position:absolute;
}
.balls{
  width:500px;
  height:320px;
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;
  top:80px;
}
```

Can anyone please shed some light on why it is acting this way?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE: There is definitely a mistake in my algorithm. I tried it now with 20 "balls" and it breaks each time now

Answer (score 0):

I have found the mistake. In my hitTest, after I have re positioned the element, I only test against the second element, and not against all the elements again. The new function, which now works 100% follows:

Placing the balls:

```
function setBalls(){
  for (i=0;i<amount;i++){
    $("#ball"+i).css('top',parseInt(Math.random()*height)+'px');
    $("#ball"+i).css('left',parseInt(Math.random()*width)+'px'); 
for (j=0;j<i;j++){
      hitTest($("#ball"+i),$("#ball"+j),j);
    }
 }
}
```

The hitTest function:

```
function hitTest(object1,object2,prevBalls){
  var left1 = parseInt(object1.css('left'));
  var left2 = parseInt(object2.css('left'));
  var top1 = parseInt(object1.css('top'));
  var top2 = parseInt(object2.css('top'));
  var width1 = parseInt(object1.width());
  var width2 = parseInt(object2.width());
  var height1 = parseInt(object1.height());
  var height2 = parseInt(object2.height());
  var horTest = false;
  var verTest = false;
  if (((left1 >= left2)&&(left1 <= left2 + width2))||((left2 >= left1)&&(left2 <= left1 + width1))){
    horTest = true;
  }
  if (((top1 >= top2)&&(top1 <= top2 + height2))||((top2 >= top1)&&(top2 <= top1 + height1))){
    verTest = true;
  }
  if(horTest&&verTest){
    console.log("hit");
    object1.css('top',parseInt(Math.random()*height)+'px');
    object1.css('left',parseInt(Math.random()*width)+'px');
    for (j=0;j<prevBalls;j++){
      hitTest(object1,$("#ball"+j),j);
    }
    hitTest(object1,object2);
  } 
}
```